# Capturing standards out of a class run by mvn exec:java

Tags: java, maven, stdout

I would like to run a main method using Maven's exec command.  I can set it up to run just fine, but the output of my class is surrounded by Maven's text.

> ```
> [INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on. 
> [INFO] Scanning for projects...
> [WARNING] 
> ...
> (actual program output)
> ...
> [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [INFO] Total time: 11.351s
> [INFO] Finished at: Fri Apr 01 11:38:15 PDT 2011
> [INFO] Final Memory: 50M/452M
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

Is there a way to just capture just the program output and not the Maven output?  Or do I need to rewrite my software to write to a file (not ideal)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Execute `mvn` with the `-q` flag to silence Maven's output.

Answer (score 1):

There's no good solution to this. It's just how the exec plugin works. You could use the exec goal and run a shell script that redirected the output.

Comment: Try the -q flag.  Works like a charm.

Comment: Unless it shuts up something else you need from the overall run.